# How to curve only part of an object?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am making a sword and require some help. Until now I have made swords in blender by making two meshes, one is the blade and handle the other is the guard. Now today I am wondering if I can make the sword one mesh and if its possible to curve part of the mesh, the guard, with out affecting the rest of the mesh.

[image]

Comment: Objects can be joined by selecting them and pressing Ctrl J. As for curving, I'm not really sure what you mean (curving in what way?). Can you upload some images illustrating what you want to do?

Comment: Yes I know how to join, as I said in my first post I have been doing that up until now. What I am asking is can I curve a section of a mesh without curving or deforming the rest of it?

http://puu.sh/97jtw/d0dcc54f1c.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to approach this is with proportional editing:

1. Press <kbd>O</kbd> to enable it (or select *Enabled* from the drop down in the header)
2. Select the tip of the guard and press <kbd>G</kbd>. Then use the mouse wheel to adjust radius as you translate the tip.

[image]

Comment: i did this but instead of mirroring it i selected both tips.http://puu.sh/97kIb/213d50628d.png