# How to wrap fingers around a cylinder (handle)?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I'm fairly new to blender, and have tried this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10812/how-to-curve-only-part-of-an-object) already, but it's actually warping the blue selected polygons. I'm trying to warp / bend the fingers adjacent to the selected polygons. My issue:

[image]

I am trying to get those 4 fingers to curve around the handle:

[image]

Comment: Well your going from simple mesh editing to armature's.
its not ehm the most simple thing to do for a starter.
but here it is
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYiAd_08-0k

Comment: Search for "blender rigging" in google and the answer will come :)

Comment: Also note that your mesh wont deform nice because you dont have good topology; you have tris and you need quads in order your mesh to deform better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rotate portions of the mesh around the 3D cursor. The position can be established by first selecting a ring of vertices in Edit Mode, and then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and choosing cursor to selected. Press the period key <kbd>.</kbd> to choose the 3D cursor location as the rotation point. Select the rest of the mesh you wish to rotate and ...rotate.

[image: Rotate around 3D cursor]

Perhaps later you will want to rig to accomplish the same thing - in which case you will want to create your mesh from quads to avoid distortion. In this case I used <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to convert the tris to quads and re-distributed the vertices. The rotation also has proportional editing enabled. While bones and weight paint can achieve the same thing, this is a good way to test bends.

[image]